# Website working fine but error in testing

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am getting this error in testing while the website is working perfectly fine. Control is a app name
Can someone suggests some changes to be done in the url or html line

```
class TestUrls(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_index_url_is_resolved(self):
        url = reverse('index')
        print(resolve(url))
```

I used this for testing and it shows the below error

```
ERROR: test_index_url_is_resolved (control.tests.test_urls.TestUrls)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bhavya/Website/control/tests/test_urls.py", line 7, in test_index_url_is_resolved
    url = reverse('index')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 673, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s
```

This is link for index html page

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href = "{% url 'control:index' %}">CCTV</a>
```

This is urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [

    #Control
    url(r'^$',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),

]
```

This is function in views:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'control/index.html'
# success_url = reverse_lazy('control:index')
def get_queryset(self):
    return Camera.objects.all()
```

Comment: what is 'control' and where is it define

Comment: For any potential help to be most effective, it would be better if you provide a larger code snippet as well as some context about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but if you are using a name for you app, such as

`app_name = "control"`

then you must include this name in the string you pass to the reverse function, like this:

`url = reverse('control:index')`